# Evaluate my proof on convergence and accumulation points

Tags: convergence-divergence

First of all, I define accumulation point as: Let $a$ be an accumulation point of $A$. $\forall \ \epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon(a) \setminus \{a\} $ contains an element of $A$.

T/F question: If $a$ is an accumulation point of $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, then there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ converging to $a$.

I'm tempted to say true by using this proof:

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, construct $B_\epsilon(a)$ such that $\epsilon = 1/n$. Then pick a point out of the ball such that $a_n \neq a$. Repeating this procedure yields a sequence and this sequence converges to $a$.

Two questions:

(1) Am I right

(2) Is it necessary that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Why or why not?

Comment: 1) yes, that is the classic proof.  2) A needs the be a closed metric space but it needn't be R.  You need a space where $B_\epsilon(x)$ will always have points other than$x $.  And you need a space where cauchy sequences must converge.

Comment: For (2), does that mean I need a *complete* metric space? What does it have to be closed?

Comment: I think one only needs a metric space for 2) to work.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about the second and third proof would work in Q. As a is in the set.  But you do need the space to be "dense" so that all B_e have more than one point.

Comment: @fleablood You don't need this. If $a$ is isolated, it is not an accumulation point according to the above definition.

Comment: It will not work on the discrete metric.  I meant complete, not closed.  That was a typo.  But it doesn't have to be complete.  Just dense.  As the accumulation point is assumed to be in A, we don't have to worry about a sequence not converging.  It will converge to a.

Comment: Doh.  You are right.  Never mind.  Any metric space only because B_e needs to make sense.  But there is a caveat.  There are metric space where B_e/{a} can be empty.  But then a can't be an accumulation point then.  And there are metrics where cauchy sequences don't converge to known points.  But then there will not be a point a, to take a series of neighborhoods around.